# Email is double encode in android

Tags: android

I want to encode email address: `asd@asd.as`

I used:

```
URLEncoder.encode(etUsername.getText().toString(), "utf-8")
```

I am expecting result: `asd%40asd.as`

but I get: `asd%2540asd.as`

Any idea why?

Comment: Did you double check that you wrote the name of a supported character encoding correctly like this `URLEncoder.encode(etUsername.getText().toString(), "UTF-8")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolve my problem. I need to add `encoded = true` to `@Path(value = "username", encoded = true)` to avoid second encoding.